# Zend 2: Correct way to add add a controller

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I am trying to work with the zend 2 framework.

My problem is that I don't quite understand how the routing from zend works.
My problem is that I don't know how to add a second controller to the routing.

Can somebody give me an example?

This is my module.config.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Website\Controller\Home',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'website' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/website',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Website\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Home',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Website',
                'route' => 'website',
                'pages' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Home',
                        'route' => 'home',
                        'action' => 'home',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),

    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Website\Controller\Home' => 'Website\Controller\HomeController',
            'Website\Controller\Leden' => 'Website\Controller\LedenController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'website/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*please use "**edit**" on your question for new addition about your problem, because all your answer as new notice about your problem is **uncomfortable** for all..*

---

with your repo i found **next problem**:

in your Website/config/module.config.php - **controllers -> invokables**: try to set leden controller with key `'Leden' => 'Website\Controller\LedenController'`

[image]

*all working after this.*

i think your *Website* module it was just renamed the Application from skeleton..

anyway the best variant for ZF2 - the modular structure (tutorial: [Album module](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-tutorial/tree/master/module),  [application.config.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-tutorial/blob/master/config/application.config.php), [Album module :: step by step](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html))

patch for your problem:

```
 module/Website/config/module.config.php | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

diff --git a/module/Website/config/module.config.php b/module/Website/config/module.config.php
index b3ff158..c128587 100644
--- a/module/Website/config/module.config.php
+++ b/module/Website/config/module.config.php
@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@ return array(
                     'route'    => '/website',
                     'defaults' => array(
                         '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Website\Controller',
-                        'controller'    => 'Home',
+                        'controller'    => 'Website\Controller\Home',
                         'action'        => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@ return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Website\Controller\Home' => 'Website\Controller\HomeController',
-            'Website\Controller\Leden' => 'Website\Controller\LedenController'
+            'Leden' => 'Website\Controller\LedenController'
         ),
     ),
     'view_manager' => array(
```

Answer (score 1):

your module.config.php is similar to the sample router in [skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L23)

right ?

so, by default the route is configured as a `/<module_name>/:controller/:action`

because ZF2 uses a module system to organise your app within each module  - see [Modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/modules.html#modules)

for example - if you want to add a new controller (I see in your config - Home & Leden Controller):

> ```
> ├───module
> │   ├───Website
> ...
> │   │   │
> │   │   ├───src
> │   │   │   └───Website
> │   │   │       ├───Controller
> │   │   │       │       HomeController.php
> │   │   │       │       LedenController.php
> ```

your controller sample:

```
namespace Website\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class HomeController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function writeAction()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

route:

```
'Website' => array(
    'type'    => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/website',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Website\Controller',
            'controller'    => 'Index',
            'action'        => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

and to your invokables:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Website\Controller\Home' => 'Website\Controller\HomeController',
        'Website\Controller\Leden' => 'Website\Controller\LedenController'
    ),
),
```

that's all, try to open

- http://example.com/website/Home/write ( /module/controller/action )
- http://example.com/website/ - call controller by default - see defaults section

for more detail **about routing** in the ZF2, see [Zend\Mvc - Routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html) and see [Routing and controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) from tutorial